# Dragging points to change the shapes

Tags: mfc, gdi

I have managed to connect 4 points where the mouse click is made using the following code.(I am using MFC).

```
  void CChildView::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags,CPoint point)
  {    
  if(m_LastPoint.x!=-1 && m_iPointAmount<6)
  {
    CDC* pDC= GetDC();
    pDC->MoveTo(m_LastPoint.x,m_LastPoint.y);
    pDC->LineTo(point.x,point.y);
  }
    m_LastPoint=point;
    m_iPointAmount++;
  }
```

The variables are initialized in the constructor as follows.

```
 m_LastPoint.x=-1;
 m_LastPoint.y=-1;
 m_iPointAmount=1;
```

I want to do the following now.

1.Whenever the mouse click is made on one of the points and dragged, the point should relocate to the new position.(so the shape is changed).

2.This should be applicable for all the four points.

Pls guide me on how to achieve this.

Comment: =) here i am again. the "m_iPointAmount<6" will make you have 5 points, but you want 4 as you said. Actually you want a closed polygon with 4 sides, so actually you should have another variable that stores the first point, so when you get to the 4th point you connect the 4th point with the first one to "close" the polygon

Comment: to do the other things you need to use OnMouseMove https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3158baat.aspx, and inside that you will have to check if the mouse is pressed and then do what you need.  but clearly here you also want to be able to "select" the point. As your username says you are a "beginner" so i think that first you should study a little bit more the basics about how MFC C++ works, how GDI works, check the functions and features available, and then try to implement something. Going like this into the darkness is really hard.

Comment: How to save the first point? Also how to select the point when the click is made? Any sample code? Pls........

Comment: I answer you with another question, How are you saving the last point?

Comment: point.x and point.y gives us the last point where the click is made.

Comment: correct, but there is a time when the last point is also the first point, and that is when the user makes the first click, right? how can you identify that?

Comment: m_LastPoint.x and m_LastPoint.y saves the first click position. Also when second click is made m_LastPoint.x and m_LastPoint.y is updated to that latest point.

Comment: right, so you have to identify when it is the first position and store that information in another place =)

Comment: That is exactly my doubt. How to identify whether it is the first point? Because for every click the OnLButtonDown function gets called and the first point will be updated for every click right?

Comment: you have "m_iPointAmount", when that variable is equal to its initialized value, then you have the first point =) I'm sorry to tell you, but this is not MFC or c++ related, this is basic programming logic on how to handle variables and informations. You really need to read a basic programming book, but it is really nice to see the effort you are putting on this, of course everyone has been where you are now, so first you need to study more about the basics of programming and then try to create this complex program of yours. I will not post the solution you need because it would deny your study

Comment: are doing this by yourself, or is this something like a school project?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get what you are saying. But I am allowed to study only if I complete this task. I really need to complete this. Can u pls help? I am doing this by myself. I dont even have friends who knows MFC.....

Answer (score 0):

## how this works

start clicking on the window until you reach the amount sepcified in m_iPolygonMaximumSides.
When you reach the amount of points specified the polygon will be closed, so now you are able to select a point.
Click near a point to select it, the drag will keep going until you click again.
To reset the polygon you will have to close the window.

## code

in the cpp file of your CChildView class add the following include, because it is used to calculate square root

```
#include <math.h>
```

in your CChildView class add the following methods and variables

```
CList<CPoint> m_PointList;
CPoint m_selectedPoint;
int m_iPolygonMaximumSides;
afx_msg void OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
void DrawPolygonFromList();
```

in the message map of your CChildView class add these lines

```
ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE()
```

in the CChildView constructor initialize m_iPolygonMaximumSides with the amount you want (4) and m_selectedPoint with (-1,-1) like

```
m_iPolygonMaximumSides = 4;
m_selectedPoint = CPoint(-1,-1);
```

then this is to be added to your CChildView cpp file, these are all the moethods used

```c++
void CChildView::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{

    //check if we already reached the maximum point number
    if (m_PointList.GetSize() == m_iPolygonMaximumSides)
    {
        //check if a point was already selected, and so we are in the drag mode
        if (m_selectedPoint.x !=-1)
        {
            //if the point was already selected it means that we want to stop the dragging,
            //so we just set the x to -1
            m_selectedPoint.x =-1;
        }
        else
        {
            //if we didn't have a point selected we have to check if the point clicked is one of our points
            //so we will use this for to search for out point
            for (POSITION pos = m_PointList.GetHeadPosition();pos != NULL;m_PointList.GetNext(pos))
            {
                CPoint currentPoint = m_PointList.GetAt(pos);
                //this is the pythagorean theorem to find a distance between two points A and B
                // distance = squareRoot( (A.x-B.x)^2+(A.y-B.y)^2)
                int distanceBetweenPoints = floor(sqrt(pow(double(currentPoint.x-point.x),2)+pow(double(currentPoint.y-point.y),2)));
                //if this distance is less than 10 pixels, then we accept it as a click on our points
                //this is just a tollerance, so we can reduce or increment it as we like
                //the smaller the tollerance nearer you will have to click to be able to select the point
                if (distanceBetweenPoints <= 10)
                {
                    //if the tollerance is met then we set the point as our selected point
                    m_selectedPoint = currentPoint;
                    //interrupt the iteration, because we don't need to look further
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //if we didn't reach the maximum point amount it means that we still have to keep going on getting the points
    else if (m_PointList.GetSize() > 0)
    {
        CDC* pDC= GetDC();
        CPoint lastPoint = m_PointList.GetTail();
        //draw a line from the previous (last) point to the new one
        pDC->MoveTo(lastPoint.x,lastPoint.y);
        pDC->LineTo(point.x,point.y);

        //if we are going to reach the maximum amount of points then we will have to close the polygon
        if (m_PointList.GetSize()==m_iPolygonMaximumSides-1)
        {
            CPoint firstPoint = m_PointList.GetHead();
            //draw a line from the current point to the first point
            pDC->MoveTo(point.x,point.y);
            pDC->LineTo(firstPoint.x,firstPoint.y);
        }
    }
    //add the point to the list only after you have done everything, only if we didn't reachthe maximum amount
    if (m_PointList.GetSize() < m_iPolygonMaximumSides)
        m_PointList.AddTail(point);
}


void CChildView::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    //check if we already have the maximum number of points
    if (m_PointList.GetSize()==m_iPolygonMaximumSides)
    {
        //check i
        if (m_selectedPoint.x != -1)
        {
            //check if we actually find the point
            POSITION posFound = m_PointList.Find(m_selectedPoint);
            if (posFound != NULL)
            {
                //update the selected point with the new one
                m_selectedPoint=point;
                //now also update the list
                m_PointList.SetAt(posFound,point);
                //draw the polygon
                DrawPolygonFromList();
            }
        }
    }
}

void CChildView::DrawPolygonFromList()
{
    //this is checked again because we might want to use this function in another place
    if (m_PointList.GetSize()==m_iPolygonMaximumSides)
    {
        //use this to clear the window
        RedrawWindow();
        //this will be used to draw
        CDC* pDC= GetDC();
        POSITION pos = m_PointList.GetHeadPosition();
        //load the first and second point
        CPoint pointBefore = m_PointList.GetNext(pos);
        CPoint currentPoint = m_PointList.GetNext(pos);
        //draw the line connecting the first and the second point
        pDC->MoveTo(pointBefore.x,pointBefore.y);
        pDC->LineTo(currentPoint.x,currentPoint.y);

        //draw the intermediary points
        while (pos != NULL) 
        {
            pointBefore = currentPoint;
            currentPoint = m_PointList.GetNext(pos);
            pDC->MoveTo(pointBefore.x,pointBefore.y);
            pDC->LineTo(currentPoint.x,currentPoint.y);
        } 
        //now close the poligon
        pointBefore = currentPoint;
        currentPoint = m_PointList.GetHead();
        pDC->MoveTo(pointBefore.x,pointBefore.y);
        pDC->LineTo(currentPoint.x,currentPoint.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting error(Undeclared Identifier) in this declaration. CList<CPoint> m_PointList; Is this correct?

Comment: did you forget to add CList<Cpoint> m_PointList; to your class?

Comment: I have added it in the view class header file.

Comment: The error I get is "syntax error : missing ; before < and unexpected tokens preceding ;

Comment: try this "#include afxtempl.h" check here for more detail about CList https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxde0zae.aspx